# Binding to boolean attribute

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to set up a binding to a boolean attribute of an element. I have a observable field im my application element:

```dart
  @observable bool test = false;
```

Now i want to bind it to an element that has a boolean attribute, like `<input type="checkbox">` and display the current value of that element:

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="{{test}}">
Value is {{test}}
<template if="{{test}}">
   Toggle button is on
</template>
```

But if I check the checkbox nothing is happening. The `testChanged` method is not called:

```dart
  void testChanged(old) {
    print('Test $test');
  }
```

I can't recall it, but wasn't there a syntax containing a question mark for binding to booleans? I can't find any resources on this. I followed the [example of Seth Ladd for binding to checkbox](https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/blob/master/web/bind_to_checkbox/my_example.html) that uses the same syntax as I use.

My initial goal was to bind to the polymer-ui-toggle-button element from the [polymer_ui_elements package](https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_ui_elements), but it doesn't work either:

```html
<polymer-ui-toggle-button value="{{test}}"></polymer-ui-toggle-button>
Value is {{test}}
<template if="{{test}}">
  Toggle button is on
</template>
```

I don't get an exception in this case, but the binding isn't working. The button itself is working fine and changes his state on toggle. I can see in the inspector that the value attribtue is toggled correctly.

Does anybody is already using a binding to a boolean and can point me to the right route or knows about issues?

**Update: [Here is my example source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/480043/test.zip).**

My Dart version:
Dart Editor version 1.0.2_r30821 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.0.2.1_r30821

Comment: when the checkbox is ticked, it'll get a value of "checked" not "true" as Dart would be expecting. Is that not it?

Comment: My mistake, I will update the question, the exeception goes away but it isn't working

Comment: Is the HTML you provided inside a custom elements template element?

Comment: Yes it is, see the test-element.html in the linked zip file

Comment: downloaded your code and it works fine (checkbox and polymer-ui-toggle-button) and I find it weird to make the toggle-botton switch without clicking it - never tried that :-) I just saw, that the checkbox doesn't switch when I click the toggle button :(

Comment: I only have both element in there to test both, I don't realy want to use this combination. Which Dart version are you using?

Comment: Just noticed that the checkobox is working for me if I compile to js, but the button can only set the var to true, but not to false again.

Comment: I have the same behaviour in Dart. Version 1.0.3_r30939 (DEV).

I see that the value in the toggle button is toggled but it is not updated in HTML.

Comment: When I add a breakpoint in toggle-button it works both ways. Seems to be a timing problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42704/discussion-between-fox32-and-zoechi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last time I tried it worked this way

```
checked?="{{isChecked}}"
```

Comment: I tired that but without success. Is there any documentation on that syntax? I updated my post with my full example code.